# Can some help me with this code? Google Sign in Firebase (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

when I select the account I want to login with, it fails. I'm confuse to whats the issue, I followed the tutorial step by step. except for this code:

```
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

because signInWithGoogle wasn't working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'home_everything.dart';

class login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _loginState createState() => _loginState();
}

class _loginState extends State<login> {
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  bool loading = false;
  bool isLogedin = false;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    isSignedIn();
  }

  void isSignedIn() async{
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLogedin = await googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    if(isLogedin){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SongHome()));
    }

    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  }
  Future handleSignIn() async{
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    if(firebaseUser != null) {
      final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection("users")
          .where("id", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
          .getDocuments();
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
      if (documents.length == 0) {
// insert the user into out collection
        Firestore.instance.collection("users")
            .document(firebaseUser.uid)
            .setData({
          "id": firebaseUser.uid,
          "username": firebaseUser.displayName,
          "profilePicture": firebaseUser.photoUrl
        });
        await preferences.setString("id", firebaseUser.uid);
        await preferences.setString("username", firebaseUser.displayName);
        await preferences.setString("photoUrl", firebaseUser.displayName);
      } else {
        await preferences.setString("id", documents[0]['id']);
        await preferences.setString("username", documents[0]['username']);
        await preferences.setString("photoUrl", documents[0]['photoUrl']);
      }
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Logged In");
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SongHome()));
    }else{
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login failed : (");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: new Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),),
        elevation: 0.5,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              handleSignIn();
            },
            child: Text("Sign In"),),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: loading ?? true,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
E/flutter (15402): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: ok I posted the  error log.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).user;
```

Comment: Please make sure to explain why this might be the right answer